# Using Array.map(), to extract values from array of key:value objects

Tags: javascript

I have been able to use the following code to extract values for a list of specific keys from an array of objects.

```
let keys = ['name', 'age'];
let employees = [
  {name: 'Matt', employeeID: 123, performance: 'good', age: 21},
  {name: 'Brian', employeeID: 321, performance: 'average', age: 32},
  {name: 'David', employeeID: 456, performance: 'best', age: 35},
  {name: 'Kevin', employeeID: 654, performance: 'poor', age: 38},
  {name: 'Barrack', employeeID: 789, performance: 'super', age: 47},

];

let extracted = employees.map(object => keys.map(element => object[element]));
console.log(extracted); //result is [[Matt, 21.0], [Brian, 32.0], [David, 35.0], [Kevin, 38.0], [Barrack, 47.0]]
```

I have a hard time understanding conceptually how using two `Array.map()` methods nested within each other works like this. Can somebody walk me through how this actually works? For instance if I want to use only one `Array.map()` method to recreate the above, I end up with an array of truncated objects that still includes `key:value` pairs.

```
let truncated = employees.map(({name, age, ...rest}) => ({name, age}));
console.log(truncated); //result is [{age=21.0, name=Matt}, {age=32.0, name=Brian}, {age=35.0, name=David}, {name=Kevin, age=38.0}, {age=47.0, name=Barrack}]
```

Comment: In the final code block, you hardcode the keys you want to retain, thereby avoiding the dynamic way, which involves an array that you need to iterate. That is what the inner `.map` does.

Comment: Ultimately, do you want an array of objects, or an array of arrays?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Array map takes an array of elements and transforms each element using the supplied function -

```js
// input
[1,3,5,7].map(a => a + 10)
```

| input | a => a + 10 | output |
| --- | --- | --- |
| `1` | `1 + 10` | `11` |
| `3` | `3 + 10` | `13` |
| `5` | `5 + 10` | `15` |
| `7` | `7 + 10` | `17` |

```js
// output
[11,13,15,17]
```

Now we look at it with a more simplified view -

```js
// in       // out
[           [ 
  1,  // =>   11,
  3,  // =>   13,
  5,  // =>   15,
  7,  // =>   17
]           ]
```

And now expand it with a level of nesting using your objects -

```js
[
  {
    name: 'Matt',          // [            [
    employeeID: 123,       //   "name", =>   "Matt",
    performance: 'good',   //   "age"        21
    age: 21                // ]            ]
  },
  {
    name: 'Brian',          // [            [
    employeeID: 321,        //  "name", =>    "Brian",
    performance: 'average', //  "age"         32
    age: 32                 // ]            ]
  },
  {
    name: 'David',          // [            [
    employeeID: 456,        //  "name", =>    "David",
    performance: 'best',    //  "age"         35
    age: 35                 // ]            ]
  },
  {
    name: 'Kevin',          // [            [
    employeeID: 654,        //  "name", =>    "Kevin",
    performance: 'poor',    //  "age"         38
    age: 38                 // ]            ]
  },
  {
    name: 'Barrack',        // [            [
    employeeID: 789,        //  "name", =>    "Barrack",
    performance: 'super',   //  "age"         47
    age: 47                 // ]            ]
  }
]
```

```js
[
  [
    "Matt",
    21
  ],
  [
    "Brian",
    32
  ],
  [
    "David",
    35
  ],
  [
    "Kevin",
    38
  ],
  [
    "Barrack",
    47
  ]
]
```

```js
[
  ["Matt",21],
  ["Brian",32],
  ["David",35],
  ["Kevin",38],
  ["Barrack",47]
]
```

Answer (score 1):

On the first iteration of `employees.map()`, `object` is the object

```
{name: 'Matt', employeeID: 123, performance: 'good', age: 21}
```

We then execute `keys.map()`.

On the first iteration, `element` is `'name'`, and we return `object[element]`, which is `'Matt'`. On the second iteration, `element` is `'age'`, and we return `object[element]`, which is `21`. `map()` combines these results into the array `['Matt', 21]`.

We then repeat the above for each object in the `employees` array, and make a list of all these results. This produces an array of arrays.

Answer (score 0):

You end up with a nested array because both `maps` return arrays. Your "inner" `map` returns an array of values based on the `keys` array, and that is returned to the "outer" `map` that's been iterating over the array of each object, which *also* returns an array.

```js
// Create a new array by mapping over each object
employees.map(object => {
  
  // For each key in the keys array return a
  // new array of only those values of the
  // properties of the object that match the key
  return keys.map(element => object[element]);
});
```

Answer (score -1):

```js
let keys = ['name', 'age'];
let employees = [
  {name: 'Matt', employeeID: 123, performance: 'good', age: 21},
  {name: 'Brian', employeeID: 321, performance: 'average', age: 32},
  {name: 'David', employeeID: 456, performance: 'best', age: 35},
  {name: 'Kevin', employeeID: 654, performance: 'poor', age: 38},
  {name: 'Barrack', employeeID: 789, performance: 'super', age: 47},

];

let extracted = employees.flatMap(object => keys.map(element => object[element]));
console.log(extracted);
```

What you are looking for should be a `flatMap`

Comment: What do you mean by "you're looking for"? He's not trying to get a different result, he wants to know how the code works.